# foreach内のInvalid valuableエラーを解決したいです。

Tags: php, cakephp

CakePHPでデータベースからusernameを検索機能を使い表示させる機能を作成しているのですが、

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: users [APP/View/User/find.ctp, line 6]
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/View/User/find.ctp, line 6]
```

というエラーで止まっています。
かなり初歩的なエラーだとは思うのですが、解決方法をご教授頂けると幸いです。

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span9">

   <table class="table">

   <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>//////エラー箇所
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo h($user['users']['id']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($user['users']['username'],'/users/find/');?></td>
        </tr>
   <?php endforeach;?>

  </table>    
</div>
<div class="span3">
    <div class="well" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Users',array('url'=>'find')); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Search user</legend>
    </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => 'Enter Username', 'class' => 'span12', 'empty' => true)); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end('Search'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Undefined variable: users` は「users という変数が定義されていません」と怒られています。
提示されたコードの範囲ではエラーの通り`foreach`文で参照するまでに`users`が定義されていません。

続くワーニングも上記の通り「未定義の配列=空の配列」を参照しているから起きているものと思われます。

検索と結果の表示を同じページで行うなら、「まだ何も検索を行っていない場合」を考慮してあげれば良さそうです。

Comment: ”isset”で変数の存在チェックをすると良いかと思います。 (こんな様な　"if(isset($users))")

Comment: ありがとうございます！usersを入力された値として定義してみます。

Comment: $users = "Hello!";
var_dump( isset($users) );としたところtrueが返ってきました。また、　　　　$users = "Hello!";
 var_dump( isset($users) );
                
 $users=$this->request->data;
 $users=$this->User->find('all', array(
  'conditions'=>array('User.username >=' => 1)));のように変数を定義してみたのですが、エラーのままです。